# An app similar to Gif Text?

Tags: ios, applications, software-recommendation, messages, graphics

Is there any application that is similar to Gif Text but with more images and continous updates ? I tried looking in the appstore but I don't think the keywords I used were good enough. I'm sure gif text is not the only app out there.

Basically a library with gif images that I can click to copy and paste in iMessage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the creator of gif text, an update is in review right now, there are about 20+ new gifs, and I'm constantly making more.

Another option is that you can create a folder in your photo album, and email yourself the gifs you want that aren't in my app, then you have access to as many as you want.

Comment: Thank you for replying here ! A really great option would be for you to add the possibility of users adding their own gifs to your program. So basically your app will store gifs and allow us to click,copy, and paste gifs in imessage etc. That would be really great.

Comment: Been using your app ever since the update, thanks for listening :)